# Facebook Wall (timeline) post from Qt Symbian 4.7

Tags: facebook, qt, symbian

I want to make a short app that can post on my Facebook wall(timeline).
My app is based on webview component (QWebView) to obtain the access token for publish stream

I can take the access token but when I try to post something, on my Facebook nothing appears.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){

    QUrl url("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");
    url.addQueryItem("client_id","my_app_id");
    url.addQueryItem("redirect_uri","https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");
    url.addQueryItem("response_type","token");
    url.addQueryItem("scope","read_stream,publish_stream");
    MainWindow::browser->load(url);
    MainWindow::browser->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_browser1_loadFinished(bool arg1)
{

        QUrl url= browser->url();
        QString strUrl = url.toString();
        qDebug()<<"URL: "<<strUrl;

        if( strUrl.contains(QString("access_token="), Qt::CaseSensitive)){

            int sIndex = strUrl.indexOf("access_token=");

            int eIndex = strUrl.indexOf("&expires_in");

            QString mAccessToken= strUrl.mid(sIndex, eIndex - sIndex);

            mAccessToken = mAccessToken.remove("access_token=");

            qDebug()<<"TOKEN: + "<<mAccessToken;

            QUrl params;

                    params.addQueryItem("access_token",mAccessToken);
                    params.addQueryItem("message","TEST !!");
                    params.addQueryItem("link","https://young-day-9284.herokuapp.com/");
                    params.addQueryItem("description","Testing");
                    params.addQueryItem("name","Test ");
                    params.addQueryItem("caption","Testing");

                    qDebug()<<"Mesajul trimis: "<<QString(params.encodedQuery());

                    QNetworkAccessManager mNetManager(this);
                    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"));
                    //request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    mNetManager.post(request,params.toString(QUrl::None).toAscii());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WebKit for this sort of program is overkill. WebKit is a full web engine and is a quite heavy component in terms of memory usage and complexity.

Try to have a look at the various OAuth implementations that exist for Qt already. For example this: https://github.com/ayoy/qoauth

QOauth even ships with some example code in the doc directory.

Comment: Doesn't work. I made the same scenario in java and works. I set the app proxy to HTTP proxy (I'm behind a proxy server). I tried outside the proxy server , on public IP and the same result....

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Is your application able to make any connections to the internet at all?

Comment: Yes I can make http request but when I tried to make https (in this case) doesn't work. I link to my project LIBS += -llibcrypto for open ssl lib, but the same result... Https requests work fine with web browser. I think there is a problem whith proxy server and https

Comment: Are you sure the `QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, QList<QSslError>)` signal isn't emitted?

Comment: Yes , I'm very sure :) No signal emitted.

Answer (score 0):

From Qt doc:

*void QUrl::addQueryItem ( const QString & key, const QString & value ):*

Note: This method does not encode spaces (ASCII 0x20) as plus (+) signs, like HTML forms do. If you need that kind of encoding, you must encode the value yourself and use **QUrl::addEncodedQueryItem.**

or don't use spaces.